# Return all freeform responses from same email

Tags: solspace-freeform

I'm making an rsvp app where a user can register for multiple events. Events may use different forms. In theory, users would use the same email address for all rsvp.

Can I get all freeform entries ie 
    {exp:freeform:entries search:email="a@a.com"}
but without form_id or form_name?

Thanks
Amanda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up writing a plugin to get all form entries with the same email.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to do a custom query using the [query module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/query/). It wouldn't be too difficult to write a query to pull from the Freeform table based on an email address.